# Why does QGIS load an image icon in layers panel when WFS layer load fails?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs

I'm trying to load WFS layers from a GeoServer and having trouble. It works in MapInfo but in QGIS the layer name appears in the layers panel but with an image icon [image]

The layer doesn't load correctly and I've checked the responses from the server using the Network Activity plugin; they all appear to be valid.

What are the reasons why QGIS may load a layer in this way as knowing the answer may help me to understand why the application doesn't seem to work with our particular GeoServer WFS service?

Comment: What URL is listed in the GetCapabilities for the GetFeature request

Comment: What WFS versions are requested. Is it simple or complex feature.  Is there any scale dependency.  Can you post an example GetFeature request that works in MapInfo, but not QGIS

Comment: So the server is not publicly accessible, as is often the case for WFS requests hence not including that data in question. The features are a test dataset so simple points or polygons depending but if I'm honest it does it for every layer on our server. There is no scale dependency or anything like that but I will check the GetCapabilities URL now.

Comment: The GetFeature request on includes a DescribeFeature URL as follows: wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType but it all seems fine and the full URL works in a web browser internally to our network. I've tried it with all three versions; same result

Comment: QGIS parses the GetCapabilities (so an incorrect URL here would cause an issue), makes a DescribeFeatureType request to get further information,, then does a GetFeature request to get the described data.

Comment: So I've now added a Geometry metadata table to my store (which is Oracle) and this means it now recognises the layer is a point/line/polygon. The result is that it is now loading in as 'valid' layer however it is not loading any actual features. That said; at least there is some progress and that may answer this question?

Is the answer that QGIS loads that icon if it can't determine the geometry type of the layer?

Comment: Can you capture the actual WFS GetFeature request made by QGIS in your GeoServer logs/ web traffic.   Could it be that the axis order is incorrect in the request?

Answer (score 1):

So I think the answer to the question is that the icon is displayed when QGIS detects the geometry type as geometry (or unknown to put it another way).

The solution for me was to use the 'Geometry metadata table' to define the geometry type and then QGIS loads the layers correctly.
[GeoServer documentation for defining geometry types in Oracle stores.](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/oracle.html#using-the-geometry-metadata-table)

My layers do not appear to actually work but that will be a different question from the one I asked.

Comment: Or possibly, after a successful DescribeFeatureType request it adds the layer icon, but then the GetFeature request fails, so you get an empty layer.